# Upgrade AngularJS to Angular QuickStart Fails Loading PlatformBrowserDynamic

Tags: angular, angularjs, systemjs

I need to upgrade an AngularJS app to the latest Angular so I'm using the Angular Upgrade guide, which instructs me to start with the quickstart repo provided by Angular.

[Angular Upgrade Guide - Setup for upgrading from AngularJS](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade-setup)

I've gotten through Step 9 and when I run "npm start", the AppComponent does not load. I'm receiving an error when SystemJS tries to load the PlatformBrowserDynamic. When I look in the developer tools, the following error is displayed.

[image: SystemJS error loading PlatformBrowserDynamic]

I've created a StackBlitz that reproduces the error and setup.  Hoping someone can point me to what I have configured incorrectly.

[StackBlitz - Reproduced Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fgrpyh?file=src%2Findex.html)

EDIT:  Fixed StackBlitz link

Comment: I'm getting 404 when trying to open the StackBlitz link.

Comment: Fixed the StackBlitz URL.  I recreated as a StackBlitz Project instead of as a StackBlitz of a hosted repository. @SzilardMihocsa